# Get cell values in two columns to two variables using macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have two columns "G" and "H" in the same sheet. I want the cell values on those two columns assigned into a two variables. I have wrote a macro as follows

```
For i = 1 To 40
rtext1 = Cells(i, "G").Value
text1 = Cells(i, "H").Value
Next i
```

But  I'm not getting the correct cell value to relevant variable. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: You are looping and setting values to variables, so you will get that last two cell values which are G40 and H40. Now, I want to confirm is how you want all values of cell from that column. I means what format. Is this OK? `rtext1 = G1 & " " & G2 & " " & G3 & ... , text1 =  H1 & " " & H2 & " " & H3 & ...` Let me know.!

Comment: No before the "Next i" I have another loop which uses rtext1 and text1 variables. once that secondary loop finishes again the second cell values should be assigned to variables. My whole code can be seen here : http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=44263919873005524050 , I'm working with unicodes and all other codes are working fine but the loop to get the cell values assign to variables.

Comment: I checked your code. I found nothing wrong in it. Where did you got wrong. I mean which line of code. Let me know..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your code. It works well. I think that when you run code, ActiveSheet is not your desired sheets. So, you not get the right value. Try this one:

```
For i= 1 To 40 Step 1

    rtext1 = Sheets("sheetname").Cells(i, "G").Value

    text1 = Sheets("sheetname").Cells(i, "H").Value

Next i
```

Comment: It's not working It seems that two variables are not getting the cell values in my macro. what is the command to get cell value to macro and assign it to a variable?

Comment: No, `Cells(i,j).Value` can get value. Somethings is wrong in your code. I don't know what because it is too much codes and can't understand the logic and flow. If not sure you can check as `MsgBox(rtext1 & " " & text1)`.

Comment: You are correct, It's getting the values to variables. But I don't understand why it's still not working. When I manually assign values to same variables it works. but when the loop runs nothing works. did i do any thing wrong with the loop commands?

Comment: No, there is no error in looping. I can't fully tested your code because I have no data. You should also post excel data. So, I can think more.

Comment: Here is the data : http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=56040525472278918457 In column B those Sinhala language words should be turned into english acording to the replace macro and values in column G and H

Comment: What is font name. I can't do anything without font. Let me know.

Comment: Here is the Font  http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=19416637771808598064 (Iskoola Potha)

Comment: I got that the main problem, VBA don't know the font(unicode). You need to solve this first.

Comment: When editor don't know the font, everytime you take the cell values, it will got "?????" always. So, if you fixed this, it will work well. This [site](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/78eeab51-f39e-423c-8afc-ebd218d658c3/how-to-make-vba-to-read-and-understand-characters-in-other-keyboard-language?forum=isvvba) is for reference.

Comment: I found the issue. when the value taken from Column H it take as whole text but It needs to be the unicode character after adding following statements it got resolved ,     For i = 1 To 38 Step 1

        rtext1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "G").Value

        text = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "H").Value

     For Each cl In Range("$B$2:$B" & Range("$B100").End(xlUp).Row)

    'MsgBox (rtext1 & " " & ChrW(text1))
    text1 = ChrW(text)

Comment: Glad to here that. You are welcome. Let me know that anything I can help for you.

Comment: Actually, you don't need second loop because you use `Range(B:B)` to replace text. So, it is not need. Just remove it. After that it will also OK.